# Variable not working in html (php)

Tags: php, html, variables

In this code, I am trying to have my variable show up in the email it sends, for some reason it is not.

Is there certain way of displaying a variable in the html? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The variable that won't show is $applicabledocument

```
// Start email send notification



                <titleNew submission by $agentclient</title>
                </head>
                <body>

                <p>New submission by $agentclient</p>
                <table border=\"1\">
                <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Property/Description</th>
                <th>Transaction Type</th>
                <th>Applicable Document</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$propertydescription</td>
                <td>$transactiontype</td>
                <td><a href=\"http:www.xxxxxx.net/xxxxxx/xxxx/\"><$applicabledocument</a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </body>
                </html>
                ";

                // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Seeing this messy code. Someone here needs to use a good HTML/PHP editor (such as Netbeans)

Comment: None of that is valid PHP, so... we can't really help you. Where are your `<?php ?>` tags?

Answer (score 6):

You can only use php variables between php tags. Right now you are using php and html without opening and closing php tags.

```
<html>
<div>Stuff</div>
<?php
//now I can use php 
echo $myVar; 
?>
<!-- now I'm back to html again-->
</html>
```

Just in case you don't know what echo does, it just takes the contents of the variable and prints it to the html document.

So `<div> <?php echo $myVar; ?> </div>`

would mean the client sees `<div>Hello Friend!</div>`

assuming `<?php $myVar = 'Hello Friend!'; ?>` was somewhere earlier in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use PHP to `echo` the contents of each variable.

```
<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $propertydescription; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $transactiontype; ?></td>
....
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For such a large string, use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to freely use $variable inside a string

```
//assuming <?php and ?> is written somewhere else
$content = <<<EOD
<html><head>
<title>New submission by $agentclient</title>
                </head>
                <body>

                <p>New submission by $agentclient</p>
                <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Property/Description</th>
                <th>Transaction Type</th>
                <th>Applicable Document</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$propertydescription</td>
                <td>$transactiontype</td>
                <td><a href="http:www.xxxxxx.net/xxxxxx/xxxx/"><$applicabledocument</a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </body>
                </html>
                EOD;

                // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

PS: I won't correct invalid HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on the php parser... a shortcut for this:

`<?=$variable;?>`